# Model binding List and creating single object

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

I have model in a view like this

```
@model List<Products>
```

I can itereate over it and show all the products. But on click of add button, I want to show a popup which will add a product (sending request to create action).

```
public JSONResult create(Product P) {}
```

Create form is also on same page, so how I will only send a newly single product?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may find the [following blog post](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/) useful.